# Should users receive an official warning before being banned for an inadequate use of SE?

Tags: feature-request, account-suspension, warning

I use Math Stack Exchange for several months. Today, I got 666 reps and posted here an inoffensive joke about the Devil's number, which I deleted 10 minutes later. Ok, I shouldn't have done that.

**Right after, the Math Stack Exchange moderators ban me for 30 days**.

As a matter of fact, I already got banned because of unwise posts on meta in my first weeks on Math Stack Exchange when I didn't fully understand what the meta was and wasn't for. Nothing mean, but without warning me, moderators banned me for a week with this message:

> It is advisable to first search on meta before posting a question. As you can see for most of your questions, users have provided links to similar discussions on meta. Some of the posts are demanding explanation of down/delete votes and some are about complaining lack of upvotes. Meta is not supposed to be used for such purposes.

As I contributed well to the main Math Stack Exchange site and to the meta (rubbish was a very little part of what I posted, and one of my post got high network with 34 upvotes) I didn't agree with them at that time. I wrote them a long answer. **They never bothered to answer this reply**. Here it is:

[image: My answer]

Here is the message they sent me today:

> Hello, 
> We're writing in reference to your Mathematics Stack Exchange account:
>
> https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1107523/albert-schr%c3%b6dinberg
>
> We have written you before about your behavior on meta being disruptive.
>
> https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35461/my-reputation-score-is-the-devils-number-should-i-be-worried 
> https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35452/colorredu-colororanges-coloryellowi-colorgreenn-colorblueg
> Indicate that the message was not as clear as we had hoped it to be. So, again, please limit your use of the meta site to posts that are relevant to the site and the community and use it within reason.
>
> Your account has been temporarily suspended for 30 days. While you’re suspended, your reputation will show as 1 but will be restored once the suspension ends.
>
> Regards, 
> Mathematics Stack Exchange Moderation Team

Last time, I thought the ban was severe. Today, I think this is totally exaggerated, regarding all my contributions to Math Stack Exchange.

**I'm not writing this post to complain, but to suggest an improvement of the banning system.**

I think moderators should **officially warn the users before banning them**, by sending them a message just like the suspension message, but without the ban, at first. It would avoid lots of disagreements. I'm really not happy of what happened today, and I don't intend to use Math Stack Exchange again. If the moderators had been more communicative, this wouldn't have happened.

Comment: You haven't been *banned*, you've been *suspended*, temporarily.

Comment: The suspension *is* the warning.

Comment: This site is also MSE, Meta Stack Exchange. Using here MSE for Math is very very confusing, don't do that.

Comment: Well then. I just rolled back some vandalism, let that (and this comment, to be sure) be *a warning* not to do so again.

Answer (score 22):

From the message you got (emphasis mine):

> We have written you ***before*** about your behavior on meta being disruptive.

The usage of the word before means this message is ***not*** your first. This means you were warned (with the shorter suspension) before being suspended for 30 days.

There is no need to change the system, you had your official warning, you ignored it, now you face consequences.